# Show Posts from Single Category Not Working

Tags: categories, loop

I have a simple loop that outputs the content of posts and then adds some navigation links at the bottom.  Wordpress is set to only show 5 posts at a time.

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation"><?php posts_nav_link(" - ", "&laquo; Newer Posts", "Older Posts &raquo;"); ?></div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

My client asked me to modify this and exclude a category from the list. I tried adding

```
<?php query_posts('cat=4'); ?>
```

before the loop.  This does filter out the desired posts, but it has messed up the navigation.  Now when I press the "Older posts" link at the bottom of the page, I don't get posts 6-10.  Instead, posts 1-5 just repeat. The url however does change to say `/news/page/2`.  If I press the "Older posts" link again, I still get posts 1-5 and the url changes to `/news/page/3`.  I have about 22 posts in total, so I can repeat this process 4 times.  Wordpress removes the "Older posts" link at the bottom after 4 clicks so it does understand how many posts I have in total (and it adjusts the url accordingly each time).  It just doesn't output the correct posts.

I also tried creating a brand new query

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query(  'cat=4'); ?>
<?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation"><?php posts_nav_link(" - ", "&laquo; Newer Posts", "Older Posts &raquo;"); ?></div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

That didn't work either.  Can someone point me the right direction?

Comment: `'cat=-4'` why there is a minus sign (`-`) before `4`?

Comment: That is what excludes the category.  'cat=4' would only show posts from category 4.  'cat=-4" shows everything EXCEPT category 4.

Comment: Your question title is *"Show Posts from Single Category Not Working"* and you are *excluding a single category but showing all others* seems self-contradictory to me. :(

Comment: Good catch.  I changed the example to get rid of the minus sign.

Comment: On which page/template is that

Comment: It's for a custom template in the index.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look the section called **Preserving Existing Query Parameters** on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Try merging in the existing query parameters; they might be getting overridden.  Instead of:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=4'); ?>
```

try

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&cat=4' );
```

Comment: `query_posts` may work for you now but this is not the recommended way. Read [first paragraph](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) in this page.